# Problem occurs to show dynamic content using jquery?

Tags: jquery, mysql, laravel

I have tried to show  the dynamic content on bootstrap modal using jquery. But The modal not show the name and content.It just show empty. Please tell me how to fix this error. Thanks in advance.

```
  @foreach($data as $items)
       <div class="col-sm-4">
               <div class="team-box">
                        <div class="team-img student-image" >
                              <img src="{{asset('photos' . $items->image)}}>
                        </div>
                       <div class="team-info">
                         <h3>
                             <span class="student-id">{{ $items->$id }}</span>
                             <span class="student-name">{{ $items->$name }}</span>
                          </h3>
                          <ul>
                              <li><b>Email</b>: {{ $items->email }}</li>
                              <li><b>Mobile</b>: {{ $items->$mobile }}</li>
                              <li> 
                               <span id="student-description" hidden>{{ $student->$description }}</span> 
                              </li>

                          </ul>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    @endforeach


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-name" id="myModalLabel">
                    </h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="col-md-12" id="modal-content">

                        </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.student-image').on('click', function () 
            {
                var description = $(this).parent().find('#student-description').html();
                var name = $(this).parent().find('#student-name').html();


                $('#myModal').find('#modal-content').html(description);
                $('#myModal').find('.modal-name').html(name);

                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You seem to be using '#' to reference classes. Use '.' instead. find('#student-name') change to find('.student-name') for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up class selectors and id selectors. You are also giving numerous elements the same id, which is not a great idea.

```
<span id="student-description" hidden>
```

Should be class `student-description`:

```
<span class="student-description" hidden>
```

The selectors should be selecting by class not id.

```
var description = $(this).parent().find('#student-description').html();
var name = $(this).parent().find('#student-name').html();
```

Should be:

```
var description = $(this).parent().find('.student-description').html();
var name = $(this).parent().find('.student-name').html();
```

The modal section of the code can just use the ids of the elements you want since there should only be one element with any given id:

```
$('#myModal').find('#modal-content').html(description);
$('#myModal').find('.modal-name').html(name);
```

Could be:

```
$('#modal-content').html(description);
$('#myModalLabel').html(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an span attribute having id exists in **student-image** class

```
  <div class="team-img student-image" >
       <img src="{{asset('photos' . $items->image)}}>
       <span id="spanid1" hidden> {{ $student->name }}</span> 
       <span id="spanid2" hidden> {{ $student->description }}</span> 
  </div>
```

Now make a bit change in jquery code :

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
       $('.student-image').on('click', function () 
        {
            var name = $("#spanid1").html();
            var description = $("#spanid2").html();

            if(description != '')
            {
                    $('#myModal').find('#modal-content').html(description);
                    $('#myModal').find('.modal-title').html(name);
            }

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
       });
  });
```